# How to remove the empty space at the bottom of the collection view in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview

I have a collectionview to populate list of data. But after binding the data, there is a large empty space at the bottom. As I'm using expander in the item template, I don't want to set the heightrequest. Any other workaround for this?

```html
<CollectionView x:Name="cview_pendingtasks" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding PendingTasks, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Margin="20, 5"
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                SelectionMode="None">
  <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
      <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="5" />
  </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Frame Padding="0, 5"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent" CornerRadius="10">
            <Expander>
                <Expander.Header>
                     ///// Header goes here //////
                </Expander.Header>
                ////////// Expander content ///////
            </Expander>
         </Frame>
      </DataTemplate>
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

[image]

Comment: Either set a height of let it fill its container.

Comment: Yeah, previously I was using the height only and was modifying the height according to the data size.  As I'm using an expander now, some content are hidden now when it is expanded.

Comment: you have to set the `height` of it as @Jason said. or it will not auto fit. other wise you can set it in a grid and set the height to `auto`

Comment: @NightWolf as you said you can set it into a grid.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will go with the height solution

Comment: The Expander control is known to show unwanted behavior when used in a `ListView` or `CollectionView`. At this time we recommend not using a `Expander` in one of these controls. Please check docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/expander